# Extract Substring from String c#

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have set of code which returns me a value "2;#bbbb" where as i want to achieve bbbb.
    Below is the code written by me.
     SPListItemCollection col = StationaryList.Items;
     for (int i = 0; i < col.Count; i++)
                            {
                                SPListItem item = col[i];
                                categoryName=item["QuizCategoryName"].ToString();
    }

```
Please tell me what do i do to achieve this.
Actual Output: "2;#bbbb"
Expected Output: bbbb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = categoryName;
string[] result = str.Split('#');
if(result.Length > 1)
Response.Write(result[1]); // your expected output
```

Answer (score 0):

This is format of lookup field which can be extracted using next sintaxys:

```
SPFieldLookupValue f = new SPFieldLookupValue("your text here");
string value = f.LookupValue;
```

This way can be extracted ID which in your case is 2

Andrew